# How to find date and time from json using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, regex

Hi I am working on RoR project with ruby-2.5.0 and Rails 5. I have a json and inside the json there is a date and time. I have to find the date and time from json using Regex. My json is as follows:-

```
{
    "Lines": [{
            "Words": [{
                "WordText": "WELCOME",
                "Left": 655,
                "Top": 442,
                "Height": 23,
                "Width": 91
            }],
            "MaxHeight": 23,
            "MinTop": 442
        },
        {
            "Words": [{
                "WordText": "0102770005",
                "Left": 752,
                "Top": 1621,
                "Height": 23,
                "Width": 131
            }],
            "MaxHeight": 23,
            "MinTop": 1621
        },
        {
        "Words": [
            {
                "WordText": "06/02/18",
                "Left": 581,
                "Top": 1826,
                "Height": 19,
                "Width": 78
            },
            {
                "WordText": "16:25",
                "Left": 671,
                "Top": 1826,
                "Height": 20,
                "Width": 46
            }
        ],
        "MaxHeight": 20,
        "MinTop": 1826
    },
        {
            "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "FOR",
                    "Left": 620,
                    "Top": 1785,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 37
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "YOUR",
                    "Left": 672,
                    "Top": 1785,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 51
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "CUSTOM",
                    "Left": 738,
                    "Top": 1785,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 79
                }
            ],
            "MaxHeight": 22,
            "MinTop": 1785
        },

        {
            "Words": [{
                "WordText": "rpos",
                "Left": 477,
                "Top": 1915,
                "Height": 22,
                "Width": 48
            }],
            "MaxHeight": 22,
            "MinTop": 1915
        },
        {
            "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "C",
                    "Left": 447,
                    "Top": 1948,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 22
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "ASH",
                    "Left": 477,
                    "Top": 1947,
                    "Height": 23,
                    "Width": 72
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "OUT",
                    "Left": 577,
                    "Top": 1947,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 79
                }
            ],
            "MaxHeight": 23,
            "MinTop": 1947
        },
        {
            "Words": [{
                "WordText": "315.47",
                "Left": 911,
                "Top": 1915,
                "Height": 22,
                "Width": 79
            }],
            "MaxHeight": 22,
            "MinTop": 1915
        },
        {
            "Words": [{
                "WordText": "GST:",
                "Left": 724,
                "Top": 1979,
                "Height": 23,
                "Width": 51
            }],
            "MaxHeight": 23,
            "MinTop": 1979
        },
        {
            "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "402!",
                    "Left": 479,
                    "Top": 2209,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 46
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "18",
                    "Left": 530,
                    "Top": 2208,
                    "Height": 23,
                    "Width": 23
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "II",
                    "Left": 570,
                    "Top": 2210,
                    "Height": 21,
                    "Width": 20
                },
                {
                    "WordText": ".28",
                    "Left": 597,
                    "Top": 2208,
                    "Height": 23,
                    "Width": 37
                }
            ],
            "MaxHeight": 23,
            "MinTop": 2208
        }
    ],
    "HasOverlay": true,
    "Message": "Total lines: 42"
}
```

Inside the json there is WordText which contains the date "08/02/18" and time "16:25" as follows:-

```
"WordText": "08/02/18" and "WordText": "16:25"
```

I have to find this date "08/02/18" and time "16:25" using regex. JSON format can be diffrent but the key and value will be same. Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @awsm, Could you please show me your expected output json?

Comment: i have to return only date/time in my output json like {
  "date": "08/02/18 16:25"
}

Comment: What if there are 2 lines that have date and time?

Comment: just return me the value of date and time i will combine own my own.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand. I'll provide Regex to find `Date` and `Time`, right?

Comment: Yes right simply tell me the regexp to find date and time

Comment: Why don't you use a JSON parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Regex to find either `Date` or `Time` in your case:

```
pattern = /\A(\d{2}:\d{2}|\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})\z/

WordText = '06/02/18'
WordText[pattern] # => '06/02/18'

WordText = '16:25'
WordText[pattern] # => '16:25'

WordText = 'WELCOME'
WordText[pattern] # => nil
```

---

I'll add some whitespaces to be more readable.

```
pattern = /\A (  \d{2}:\d{2}    |   \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}   ) \z/
```

`\A` and `\z`: start of string and end of string

`\d`: is any digit

`\d{2}`: is any 2 digits

Comment: will i have to convert my json into string and then i can pass this pattern. but date and time is not constant it can be different with different json.

Comment: You need to go to each line and get `WordText` then apply the pattern.
And the pattern will cover your case, eg: `'01/01/18'[pattern] => '01/01/18'`, or `'12:34'[pattern] => '12:34'`, ....

Comment: Did you mean the time can be either `06/02/18` or `2 June 2018`, huh?

Comment: No time will be in same format. Thanks for help its worked.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i use %r around regular expression?

Comment: `%r(\A(\d{2}:\d{2}|\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})\z)`

Comment: Is there any way to find date first and then time. your regex returns sometimes time first and then date. i want fix order.

Comment: My pattern is `/\A(foo|bar)\z/`, so you can swap them (foo & bar) to get your expected result.

Comment: i tried to swap but still its giving the wrong order sometimes. Please help

Comment: The easiest way is to extract to 2 patterns: `time_pattern = /\d{2}:\d{2}/` and `date_pattern = %r(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})`

Comment: i have mentioned above json order may vary.

Comment: i tried hash.to_s[/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/] it returns the date can you tell me how can i get the time as well?

Comment: No no, you should loop to each `:Words`, then get `:WordText` and use `Regex`. We can't get everything in 1 regex.

Comment: i am using %r{\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}|\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}} it gives an error Use // around regular expression. please help me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to find date and time from JSON using regex

```js
var objectLines ={
    "Lines": [{
            "Words": [{
                "WordText": "WELCOME",
                "Left": 655,
                "Top": 442,
                "Height": 23,
                "Width": 91
            }],
            "MaxHeight": 23,
            "MinTop": 442
        },
        {
            "Words": [{
                "WordText": "0102770005",
                "Left": 752,
                "Top": 1621,
                "Height": 23,
                "Width": 131
            }],
            "MaxHeight": 23,
            "MinTop": 1621
        },
        {
        "Words": [
            {
                "WordText": "06/02/18",
                "Left": 581,
                "Top": 1826,
                "Height": 19,
                "Width": 78
            },
            {
                "WordText": "16:25",
                "Left": 671,
                "Top": 1826,
                "Height": 20,
                "Width": 46
            }
        ],
        "MaxHeight": 20,
        "MinTop": 1826
    },
        {
            "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "FOR",
                    "Left": 620,
                    "Top": 1785,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 37
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "YOUR",
                    "Left": 672,
                    "Top": 1785,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 51
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "CUSTOM",
                    "Left": 738,
                    "Top": 1785,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 79
                }
            ],
            "MaxHeight": 22,
            "MinTop": 1785
        },

        {
            "Words": [{
                "WordText": "rpos",
                "Left": 477,
                "Top": 1915,
                "Height": 22,
                "Width": 48
            }],
            "MaxHeight": 22,
            "MinTop": 1915
        },
        {
            "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "C",
                    "Left": 447,
                    "Top": 1948,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 22
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "ASH",
                    "Left": 477,
                    "Top": 1947,
                    "Height": 23,
                    "Width": 72
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "OUT",
                    "Left": 577,
                    "Top": 1947,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 79
                }
            ],
            "MaxHeight": 23,
            "MinTop": 1947
        },
        {
            "Words": [{
                "WordText": "315.47",
                "Left": 911,
                "Top": 1915,
                "Height": 22,
                "Width": 79
            }],
            "MaxHeight": 22,
            "MinTop": 1915
        },
        {
            "Words": [{
                "WordText": "GST:",
                "Left": 724,
                "Top": 1979,
                "Height": 23,
                "Width": 51
            }],
            "MaxHeight": 23,
            "MinTop": 1979
        },
        {
            "Words": [{
                    "WordText": "402!",
                    "Left": 479,
                    "Top": 2209,
                    "Height": 22,
                    "Width": 46
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "18",
                    "Left": 530,
                    "Top": 2208,
                    "Height": 23,
                    "Width": 23
                },
                {
                    "WordText": "II",
                    "Left": 570,
                    "Top": 2210,
                    "Height": 21,
                    "Width": 20
                },
                {
                    "WordText": ".28",
                    "Left": 597,
                    "Top": 2208,
                    "Height": 23,
                    "Width": 37
                }
            ],
            "MaxHeight": 23,
            "MinTop": 2208
        }
    ],
    "HasOverlay": true,
    "Message": "Total lines: 42"
};
var date;
var time;
objectLines.Lines.forEach(function (element) {
    element.Words.forEach(function (el) {
        var dateRx = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2})$/;
        if(el.WordText.match(dateRx)){
            date =el.WordText;
        }
        var timeRx = /^(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})$/;
        if(el.WordText.match(timeRx)){
            time =el.WordText;
        }
    });
});
console.log(date);
console.log(time);
var reselt = { "date": date +' ' + time};
console.log(reselt);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i use this regex in rails?

Comment: you can regex in rails like this /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2})$/.match("08/02/18") 
for more information you can check https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html

Comment: but date and time is not fixed it can be different.

Comment: For pattern match you can follow fongfan999 post

Comment: Thanks @ Mohammad Ali Rony